# Typescript Assert Field Value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm currently using https://github.com/stephenh/ts-proto to generate TypeScript types from protobuf messages using type unions for `oneOf` fields.

A sample type can be shown like this:

```
export interface Milestone {
  milestoneLabel?: 
     { $case: 'milestoneType', milestoneType: MilestoneType } |
     { $case: 'customMilestone', customMilestone: CustomMilestone };
  targetDate: Date | undefined;
}
```

Now, later in the code, I want to have a function like this:

```
export function getCustomMilestones(milestones: Milestone[]): Milestone[] {
  return milestones.filter(milestone => milestone.milestoneLabel?.$case === 'customMilestone');
}
```

Problem is, the TypeScript language server / compiler doesn't understand that the return type of this function has a filter on the type union, so I need to assert the `$case` again when trying to read that field.

Is there a way to tell the compiler the output of the function has a specific type set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Lesiak's answer is correct, I would like to expand: You can also use `as` to "cast" to a specific type. As long as you are sure that your cast is reliable, this is as good as a regular type guard.

Example ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/FAFwngDgpgBAsgSwDZQM4gPYDsoBVKwC8MWArgLYBGUATgNygEwDCp6G5iK7OMx6NBFgDmDYFAAeEDDRAwhIWgDMAhgGNYXNJl4BvYDEMxyybdigAZFdSQB+AFwGjz3TAAkalaij2YAchNuHTwCPwAaY1MeEOhfLWj8aBgAXxgAHydnQ1cPLx9-NTZMTijg8JhC9hKg819WKvjglIZnEBUaYSgQABEVRV9exXSYUiwAEyglISgxhmTgBeAlUbUQBGwYKaRFGkbzeuKACnbhONLzAG0AXQBKXwBBGhoVMAAePd4AMhhdQLMcKw2Xw5TzeXx+SrFD5QPwpZIAPh+mRgNC6pBoWBgJwAdFsdoc-tE+IjCcFsaTzICoHZsblvHxCMQIUUONC-DcsagsVgwHMFig5BScKgzjUcNc+DBrmIlDIYIcBTAJDAMEpNsgdtCDhwCedhTcOfpnIqwHUWdV-kQleS9ZZrNTsZDWba+cAgA)):

```js
function filterMilestoneCustom(arg: Milestone[]): Array<Milestone & {milestoneLabel: { $case: 'customMilestone' }}> {
    return arg.filter(milestone => milestone.milestoneLabel?.$case === 'customMilestone') as any;
}

let milestones: Milestone[] = [];

for (let x of filterMilestoneCustom(milestones)) {
    let y: CustomMilestone = x.milestoneLabel.customMilestone;
}
```

Note that it is not necessary to declare a helper interface. The type `Milestone & {milestoneLabel: { $case: 'customMilestone' }}` is correctly recognized by the compiler.

The downside is that you have to write such a function for every `oneof` case. The problem could be solved in a generic way if ts-proto did not make the `oneof` property optional.

The `oneof` union type in ts-proto is based on [my proposal](https://github.com/stephenh/ts-proto/issues/74#issuecomment-636862947). Since then, I wrote a protobuf plugin that also uses union types for `oneof`. But it uses `undefined` for the case when nothing is selected. The generated interface looks (basically) like this:

```js
export interface Milestone {
    milestoneLabel:
        { $case: 'milestoneType', milestoneType: MilestoneType } |
        { $case: 'customMilestone', customMilestone: CustomMilestone } |
        { $case: undefined };
    targetDate: Date | undefined;
}
```

This makes it possible to write the following type guard and filter function:

```js
type MilestoneCase<C extends Milestone["milestoneLabel"]["$case"]> = Milestone & {milestoneLabel: {$case: C}};

function isMilestoneCase<C extends Milestone["milestoneLabel"]["$case"]>($case: C, milestone: Milestone): milestone is MilestoneCase<C> {
    return milestone.milestoneLabel.$case === $case;
}

function filterMilestoneCase<C extends Milestone["milestoneLabel"]["$case"]>(milestones: Milestone[], $case: C): MilestoneCase<C>[] {
    const is = (ms: Milestone): ms is MilestoneCase<C> => isMilestoneCase($case, ms);
    return milestones.filter(is);
}
```

Which can be used like this ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAsglgGwgZ2AewHYQCrmgXigwFcBbAIwgCcBuAKFEigGFjU1T4l2spDUqcDAHN6dCAA8waKsChDg1AGYBDAMbQuKdLwDedKIailE2zBAAyKyggBcBo491QAJGpXIItqAHIT3HRw8HwAaY1MeIMhvLUjcJgBfKAAfB0dDZzcPL181NnROCMDQqDz2QoDzb1Zy2MCoJNT0o0z3T29iDAATCCUhCC6G+kdgFSphCGAAERVFbxnFFKhOnr6sLvoEujoAeh2oAAsIBEgqUrQe7cZNIvNmbIAeZihJRW7kWFusAG0AIn8zFgrDZfgBdP5ZTxggB8fE+lV4ADIoLoAZFgcdvLpITlmAkEmIlJ01MA4Jh5Mg6ndHs9XhB3vDARA-mjAhiEGCIW0IDCABQ46phVlVRmRACU3mFvDgHypWHuniesP0jiok2IVAw4QREAAdFLLNZjrqcXx8IQcZttkSMCSyVq+ghFFQ5RAFRAni8JG8urKvsz-v72Zzfji+QbkDF-d9QWEBSwJaLAu6lTGUWlzhhUBS4bzSJGk+ZE-mc66U8xYfhYTKy9l+dyhcgxcMjGrgBqtRHdY7nbyZc26Ftdvs2CoJtskHII1GdWnCDGxJPSvkOK6PoQe9Ra548-7kGFfmUCq7fgOlDIoLylxIoGglMvanuxenHEuQNUVxUmXCJPqg0aEF1I9V39K06CXA14hQOFNxdf13V3HV9ygQMdSg096HPM4r0mKAbzvbUmSgpsXyMN8ZyIvAfz-HV2RoyjIDApcEAAgBVbpen6QYN0QZ1twgRCmWQlZOPWM8LxwuR8PvFibHY1YuOfFUyNw99lg4tYBmog06MtQc6CAA)):

```js
let milestones: Milestone[] = [];

let customMilestones = filterMilestoneCase(milestones, "customMilestone");
for (let x of customMilestones) {
    let y: CustomMilestone = x.milestoneLabel.customMilestone;
}

let milestoneTypes = filterMilestoneCase(milestones, "milestoneType");
for (let x of milestoneTypes) {
    let y: MilestoneType = x.milestoneLabel.milestoneType;
}

let labelUndefined = filterMilestoneCase(milestones, undefined);
for (let x of labelUndefined) {
    let y: undefined = x.milestoneLabel.$case;
}
```

If you add a case to your `oneof`, you do not need to write a new function.

See [protobuf-ts](https://github.com/timostamm/protobuf-ts) for the plugin. The main benefit over ts-proto is probably that is it written completely from scratch and does not need protobuf.js or Long.js. The code size for web apps is [considerable smaller than ts-proto](https://github.com/timostamm/protobuf-ts/blob/v1.0.3/MANUAL.md#code-size-vs-speed) and you can do some interesting things with reflection and custom options.

Comment: Very nice!! I like what you did with your oneOf implementation! Your code snippet is very much inline with what I was thinking. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Use an [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
interface CustomMilestoneWrapper {
  milestoneLabel: { $case: 'customMilestone', customMilestone: CustomMilestone };
  targetDate: Date | undefined;
}

function isCustomMilestoneWrapper(milestone: Milestone): milestone is CustomMilestoneWrapper {
    return milestone.milestoneLabel?.$case === 'customMilestone'
}

function getCustomMilestones(milestones: Milestone[]): CustomMilestoneWrapper[] {
  return milestones.filter(isCustomMilestoneWrapper);
}
```